# add additional filter only when a condition is met

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am trying to apply additional filter when my condition is met, that is when reg_number = '22162' I have to again filter with mdate = '2023-10-20' else i dont want to filter with mdate, but only with reg_number = '13352'

Code below:

```
SELECT * FROM car_details
WHERE reg_number LIKE
  CASE WHEN @reg_number = '22162' THEN 
    '22162' AND mdate = '2023-10-20'
  ELSE
    '13352'
  END
```

But I get error as below:

```
TYPE_MISMATCH: line 15:5: Logical expression term must evaluate to a boolean (actual: varchar(5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM car_details
WHERE (reg_number = '22162' AND mdate = '2023-10-20')
OR reg_number = '13352'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE` statement doesn’t return a boolean value. It returns a single value that either is the result of the `THEN` clause or the `ELSE` clause.

You can reframe the query as:

```
Select *
From car_details
Where
(reg_number = '22162' and mdate = '2023-10-20') or
(reg_number = '13352' and @reg_number != '22162')
```

When `reg_number` is `'22162'`, it wil also filter with `mdate = '2023-10-20'` and for other cases, it will only filter with `reg_number = '13352'`

Comment: Welcome Gaurav.  The answer is well formatted.  the second filter seems to have a redundant part because if the reg_number is 13352, then it cannot also be 22162.  Nice explanation of why the case statement is not working.

Comment: Hello Abraham, yeah i just realize that we don't need the 2nd line. Thanks for correcting me. 